# What number representation is this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p$ is a positive prime number, put $p! = \textrm{lcm}(2, 3, 5, \dots, p) = p\cdots3\cdot2$. Then every non-negative integer can be written uniquely as:

$x_1 + 2\cdot x_2 + 3\cdot 2 x_3 + \dots + p! \cdot x_p$,  where each $x_p$ is indexed over the primes $p$ such that $p! \leq x$ and $0\leq x_i \lt \sigma(i)!, \ \forall i$ where $\sigma(i)$ is the next prime after $i$.

Divide up the numbers into divisions of $2$ integers, then divisions of $2\cdot 3$ integers, and so on, $x_p$ addresses what $p!$ block to be on and within that block, $x_{p-1}$ addresses what sub-$x_{p-1}$ block to be in and so on... to add up to the number $x$.

It is unique since each $x$ is in one and only one box on each level.

Comment: It's a particular kind of [mixed radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) number representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hardmath commented, this is a mixed radix representation. In particular, your numbers $p!$ are called *primorials* (they are often notated $p_i\#$), and the system is called a [primorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix#Primorial_number_system).

Answer (score 3):

If you had taken the $\operatorname{lcm}$ operation more seriously, and used $\operatorname{lcm}(1..n)=\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,4, \dots, n)$ as the place values (for $\operatorname{lcm}(1..(n-1)) \neq \operatorname{lcm}(1..n)$, i.e. for prime powers $n=p^r$) in your mixed radix number representation, then you would have got the [LCM numeral system](https://oeis.org/wiki/LCM_numeral_system).

It is closer in its properties to the factorial number system than to the primorial number system. It seems to feel like a slightly optimized version of the factorial number system (and fixes the drawbacks of the primorial number system compared to the factorial number system):

> This may be the "smallest" product-based numbering system that has a unique finite representation for every rational number. In this base 1/2 = .1 (1*1/2), 1/3 = .02 (0*1/2 + 2*1/6), 1/5 = .0102 (0*1/2 + 1*1/6 + 0*1/12 + 2*1/60). — Russell Easterly, Oct 03 2001

However, the factorial number system might still have slightly better properties. For example, if an arbitrarily huge number is divided by a fixed number $k$ (assumed to be small), then the factorial number system only needs to know the lowest $i+2k$ digits of the huge input number for being able to write out the lowest $i$ digits of the result. The LCM number system also only need to look ahead a finite number of digits for writing out the lowest $i$ digits of the result. The exact look ahead is harder to determine, it should be more or less the lowest $i+ik$ lowest digits of the huge input number.

However, the LCM number system also has advantages over the factorial number system. Just like the primorial number system, it allows a simple and relatively fast multiplication algorithm. The numbers can be quickly converted into an optimal [chinese remainder representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) and back:

$x_2 + 2 x_3 + 6 x_4 + 12 x_5 + 60 x_7 + \dots + \operatorname{lcm}(1..(p^r-1)) x_{p^r} \ = \ x \ $ with $\ 0\leq x_{p_i^{r_i}} < p_i$.

$x_2 = x \mod 2$
$x_2 + 2 x_3 = x \mod 3$
$x_2 + 2 x_3 + 2 x_4 = x \mod 4$
$x_2 + 2 x_3 + x_4 + 2 x_5 = x \mod 5$
$x_2 + 2 x_3 + 6 x_4 + 5 x_5 + 4 x_7 = x \mod 7$
$\dots$
$x_2 + 2 x_3 + 6 x_4 + \dots + \operatorname{lcm}(1..(p_i^{r_i}-1)) x_{p_i^{r_i}} = x \mod p_i^{r_i}$

So to multiply $x$ and $y$, one determines an upper bound for the number of places of $z = x\cdot y$, then computes value of $x$ and $y$ modulo all those places, multiplies them separately for each place (modulo $p_i^{r_i}$), and then converts the result back to the LCM representation. The conversion back is easy, since one can first determine $z_2$, then $z_3$ by subtracting $z_2$ from the known value $z \mod 3$ before converting it to $z_3$, then $z_4$ by subtracting $z_2+2z_3$ from the known value $z \mod 4$ before converting it to $z_4$, and so on.

This chinese remainder representation is optimal in the sense that the individual *moduli* are as small as possible for being able to represent a number of a given magnitude. The LCM number system may be even more optimal than the primorial number system in this respect. (It should be possible to do the computations modulo $p_i^{r_i}$ only for the biggest $r_i$, due to the structure of the LCM number system.)